# Understanding different padding rules between gcc/clang vs msvc2015 when inheriting multiple empty classes

Tags: c++, struct, multiple-inheritance

I am seeing different behaviours when it comes to multiple inheritance of empty classes in gcc/clang vs msvc2015. I was wondering if somebody would know what in the standard allows for such differences.

```
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

class Empty1 {};
static_assert(sizeof(Empty1) == 1, "Expected size of 1 for Empty1");

class Empty2 {};
static_assert(sizeof(Empty2) == 1, "Expected size of 1 for Empty2");

class Empty3 : Empty2, Empty1 {};
static_assert(sizeof(Empty3) == 1, "Expected size of 1 for Empty3");

class Int1 { uint32_t i; };
static_assert(sizeof(Int1) == 4, "Expected size of 4 for Int1");

class Int2 : Empty1 { uint32_t i; };
static_assert(sizeof(Int2) == 4, "Expected size of 4 for Int2");

class Int3 : Empty2 { uint32_t i; };
static_assert(sizeof(Int3) == 4, "Expected size of 4 for Int3");

class Int4 : Empty3 { uint32_t i; };
static_assert(sizeof(Int4) == 8, "Expected size of 8 for Int4");
static_assert(sizeof(Int4) == 4, "Expected size of 4 for Int4");
```

This codes, on msvc2015 generates:

```
error C2338: Expected size of 4 for Int4
```

While gcc and clang generate this instead:

```
error: static_assert failed "Expected size of 8 for Int4"
```

In other words, msvc2015 does not add any byte when inheriting from an empty class, but it does when inheriting from multiple ones.  Is undefined behaviour in C++?

Comment: The Empty Base Optimization is just that: an optimization. The compiler doesn't have to do it

Comment: So the expected behaviour when there is no empty base optimization is to have 1 byte for the empty base, then 3 padding for alignment, then 4 for the `uint32_t` = 8 bytes total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MSVC doesn't do this optimization so that code it compiles can be ABI compatible with older versions of the compiler. However, [if you use `__declspec(empty_bases)`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/optimizing-the-layout-of-empty-base-classes-in-vs2015-update-2-3/), you can tell MSVC to enable this optimization:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define EBO_ENABLE __declspec(empty_bases)
#else
#define EBO_ENABLE
#endif

class EBO_ENABLE Empty3 : Empty2, Empty1 {};
static_assert(sizeof(Empty3) == 1, "Expected size of 1 for Empty3");
```

[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/PRqRwH)

Comment: Awesome. It seems like default behaviour for msvc is to optimize the first empty class, and then add 1 byte for each additional. After adding 6 empty classes, my `sizeof()` grew from `8` -> `12`. I wasn't aware that this was configurable in msvc, thanks!

Comment: Is there a similar `__declspec` or attribute to enable MSVC to store things in the tail-padding of non-standard-layout subobjects/bases in general, the way the Itanium ABI does by default? `__declspec(empty_bases)`, as the name implies, affects _empty_ bases, not all bases with tail padding in general.